# jQuery infinite animation causing call stack error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-color

I'm using the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery color. I am trying to use animations to change the colors of my container infinitely. But when I run the following code, I get the error: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". The animation loop is working correctly, but it blocks the rest of my jQuery code from executing. I don't know where the stack overflow is coming from..!

```
  let $container = $("#container");
  let colours = ["56, 68, 97", "97, 56, 80", "42, 74, 53", "104, 66, 44"];

  (function colourAnimation() {
    colours.forEach((colour) => {
      $container.animate({"color": "rgb(" + colour + ")",
                          "background-color": "rgba(" + colour + ", 0.2)",
                          "border-color": "rgba(" + colour + ", 0.7)",
                        }, 2500);
    });
    $container.animate({}, 0, "", colourAnimation);
  })()
```

Comment: As robut said, you calling your function as soon as it finishes. So, the function basically being infinitely being called. Did you mean to put that last line in your function outside of the function?

Comment: I need the function to be infinitely called for the animation to loop indefinitely. Unless if there's an alternative way to achieve this effect without the stack error.

Comment: You could use `setInterval(colourAnimation, time);` where time should be in milliseconds. An explanation here - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 1):

Your `function colourAnimation()` ends with a call to a method `animate`, whose fourth parameter was passed `colourAnimation`.
The docs @ https://api.jquery.com/animate/ indicate that that 4th argument is

> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per
>   matched element.

Of course the code would recurse infinitely ?

Comment: Yes but shouldn't the call be made at the end of the animation (in this case every 4*2500ms)? Getting the call stack error suggests (to me) that the callback isn't waiting for the animation duration.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your code to be run infinitely, just use `setInterval(function, time)` where time is in milliseconds. A better explanation can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: My understanding is that using `setInterval` would be poor practice in this context due to possibility of introducing race conditions.

Comment: I know that my code above should be working somehow, but either I am missing something in terms of syntax or I am misunderstanding something fundamental about callbacks or IIFEs.

Comment: @liphenste sorry for the very late response, but setInterval is the only solution